# Different background colors for timelsots Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show availability timeslots in fullcalendar. So want to color the background of cells depending on their availability. For example : want to red color the cells from 7AM-11AM on monday. This should not be like an event but just like a background event which can be clicked to add an event.This info will eventually be sourced by json sring. I did search for this but all posts were quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a request for this feature and most of the answers are gathered in one place. See this, please: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144
I hope it helps.